# Why do I keep getting the "result2:"? I just want to get what I said

Tags: python, text, speech

```
def get_audio(): r = sr.Recognizer() with sr.Microphone() as mic: audio = r.listen(mic) said = "" try: said = r.recognize_google(audio) said = said.capitalize()
except Exception as e:
print(str(e))  
return said
```

output:

```
result2: {   'alternative': \[   {   'confidence': 0.94540769,   'transcript': 'hello my friend'}, {'transcript': 'hello my son'}, {'transcript': 'hello mission'}, {'transcript': 'hello Michelle'}, {'transcript': 'hello Michelin'}\], 'final': True} Hello my friend
```

I just want to get my voice to text and not the "result2"

Comment: Python indentation is important; please fix yours.

Comment: `return audio`?